# Multiple producer, multiple consumer using slim version of AutoResetEvent with counter

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, producer-consumer

I have a method that uses heavy concurrency to generate a lot of entries (hundreds of thousands) in a specified `ConcurrentBag<T>`. I also have many consumers of that collection. Is there any class that would allow me to implement concurrent (as few locks as possible) multiple-producers multiple-consumers pattern?

I was thinking about some kind of slim `AutoResetEvent` with inbuilt counter. Producers would simply call `.Set()`, which would increment the internal counter, then release `min(counter, numOfWaitingThreads)` threads, and set the counter  to `counter -= numOfReleasedThreads`. When consumers would call `.Wait()`, they would first check the internal counter, and if it's higher than 0, simply `Interlocked.Decrement` it and NOT block, but just pass straight through. If it was 0, then just wait for the signal (block). It would be nice if there was a `.Wait(bool)` that  would allow me to pass in `true` and that would wait using `SpinLock` for a while and then revert to locking in case there wasn't any signal for way too long.

So I wonder, is there any inbuilt or custom class that implements these features? Since concurrency is somewhat hard to get absolutely correct all the time,  I would prefer to use well-tested solution rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Also the best thing ever would be if I could call `await .WaitAsync()` too!

Comment: That class [already exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant Can you elaborate on how does Semaphore apply when the `capacity` is not constant and is determined by the concurrent operation of many producers?

Comment: Based on your description -- producer/consumer pattern with multiple producers and multiple consumers -- it sounds as though all you really need to do is wrap your `ConcurrentBag<T>` object in a `BlockingCollection<T>` object. Consumers can call `GetConsumingEnumerable()`; they will block (using an efficient mechanism) when the collection is empty, and when items are added, consumers will be unblocked as necessary to consume those items. Producers can use the `Add()` method to add items to be consumed. If that doesn't address your question, you need to be specific about why it doesn't.

Comment: Also, re: your last sentence: what `WaitAsync()` method do you want to call? Where do you want to call it?